# How to deal with multiple versions of Automake in configure.ac

Tags: build, configure, autotools, automake

I would like to selectively omit certain flags in my call to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` in my `configure.ac` depending on the Automake version. Is there a way to do that?

The specific problem I'm dealing with is that Automake 1.12 introduced some portability-related warnings (`-Wextra-portability` and `-Wportability`) that I'd like to disable (since I use `-Wall` and `-Werror` so I can't just ignore the irrelevant warnings):

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror -Wno-extra-portability -Wno-portability gnu foreign])
```

This works fine for Automake 1.12, but earlier versions of Automake error out because they don't know about those flags. Is there a way to only include those flags if we're running with Automake >= 1.12?

I tried using `m4_version_compare` but that didn't work (plus I don't think it really even makes sense to use that since it checks the Autoconf version, not the Automake version...)

[Here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2009-08/msg00035.html)'s a solution to a similar problem that involves patching `configure.ac` in `autogen.sh`, which I would like to avoid...

Comment: You could just distribute the latest automake components with the package for a self-contained build system - which is the point of the autotools: `automake [--foreign] --add-missing --force-missing --copy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't cleanly do that in automake.  If you want something like that you'll have to patch `configure.ac` in the bootstrap script (`autogen.sh`).

Easier still, just require automake 1.12.

The problem is that the automake version number that you want to compare (written to `configure` as `am__api_version`) is *not* provided in the M4sugar layer.  Not having that information there makes it hard to fix past versions of automake.

EDIT:  I thought of a different way of way of doing the same thing without patching `configure.ac` using `autogen.sh`, but the end result is the same.  The `make dist` tarball will still have a "baked in" version of automake options based on the automake version of whoever built the tarball.  But really this is no different than just setting an automake version with options.